# How do I reduce the size of Flash frame-by-frame animations?

Tags: flash, animation, memory

I've been making a game where you have a man dancing and you have 6 buttons, and whenever you click any of those he does some dance move. So basically i made 7 total frames on the main timeline, and first button has a code:

```
on (press) {
gotoAndPlay(2): }
```

and in every frame where he does some dance move i use the

```
attackMovieClip("mc","mc",depth)
```

code to attack the symbol which is actually a 60 frame animation. So after i added those 6 dance moves my *.fla* file is 60Mb big, is there any way to reduce the size? By the way all the pictures i used for the animations in the symbols are *not* lossless.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid raster images whenever possible. If you must then try and optimize them outside of flash to be as small as possible.

Also try and reuse images if at all possible. You may find you can  "slice" your images into several reusable images (ie. the arms and legs etc).

Timeline length makes no difference to the file size, only your script and assets in the library.

Comment: yes yes i know about the timeline length, but it really bugs me how the file is so big for a game so simple, i mean games like kingdom rush or some other very popular big flash games are like 34 Mb top, thanks for the tips :)

Comment: What are the sizes and resolutions of the images you are importing? If you're using photoshop try "save for web" to optimize. Also possibly reduce dimensions of the images as well.

Comment: Well actually i am using the already existing game from miniclip called dancing bush, and i just record the dance with a recording software, then break it into frames, make a new movie clip symbol, import all frames to stage, add new layer and in that layer the face, and it's weird, images are 300-350kb each, and every dance move is 60 frames on average, and that should be 20Mb for each dance i think, but it's lower, because the whole file is 54Mb , i just don't really know how to make these animations good, i just made games before, not the animations :\

Comment: game size is 600x400 and dance animations are about 400x300